# Event Order of form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events

I would like to know the event order of form which is executed while opening form.

I am showing my form using following code and the code in form_load event executes twice.
Once when the form variables are initialised and second when form is displayed. I want it to execute once only.

form showing code:

```
dim f = new myForm();
f.InitControls()
f.setUIN('222')
f.showDialog()
```

form_load event:

```
call InitControls()
```

here InitControls is called like:

```
1.) InitControls    -> OK
2.) SetUIN          -> OK
3.) Initcontrols    -> Again executed which is Not ok
```

I want it in order:

```
1.) InitControls
2.) SetUIN
```

Comment: http://codebetter.com/paullaudeman/2005/04/17/windows-forms-basic-events-in-the-lifecycle-of-forms-and-controls/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- you call `f.InitControls()` so this execute it once.
2- you call `dim f = new myForm()` method which calls `InitializeComponent()`
 this will execute it again.

if you want that order then call

```
dim f = new myForm()
f.setUIN('222')
f.ShowDialog()
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: sorry it won't work... coz setUIN should execute before showing form as it will populate the related data of 222

Comment: no its also not working. its calling setUIN before InitControls